# How to display a detailed view on startup for a NavigationView (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, navigationview

[This tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input) uses a `NavigationView` to display a `List` of elements which can be clicked, leading to a detailed view, `LandmarkDetail`. On an iPhone, the UI uses the `StackNavigationViewStyle()` which looks and works fine, but on an iPad the `NavigationView` is displayed on the side. I want to be able to fill up the remaining space with a detailed view (see below).

[image: Actual vs desired output]

I have tried to display the detailed view, `LandmarkDetail`, beside the `NavigationView` like so:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
                    Text("Favorites only")
                }

                ForEach(filteredLandmarks) { landmark in
                    NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Landmarks")
            
            LandmarkDetail(landmark: ModelData().landmarks[0])
        }
    }
```

This approach works fine for the iPad, but produces unexpected results (overlapping tiles, etc.) on the iPhone (see below). Is there a better way for achieving my desired results?

[image]

Thanks for any help and I apologise about potential obvious mistakes, etc. This is my first time using SwiftUI and there are noticeably less resources available than for Android development.

Comment: Even on the iPhone, with a big enough screen in landscape mode, I believe you'll get the iPad-style system of the list and detail view displayed at the same time. Therefore, you *might* want to check the size class and conditionally display the `LandmarkDetail` only if the size class is big enough. There may be a better solution, but that's what jumped to mind immediately for me.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a way of checking that? I've attempted using Size Classes and had no luck.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-different-layouts-using-size-classes

Comment: Same result unfortunately, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a modifier which programmatically assigned the `NavigationView` style depending on the target device fixed this issue.

```
extension View 
{
    func navigationStyleModification() -> some View
    {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
        {
            return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()))
        } else
        {
            return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle()))
        }
    }
}
```

The modifier can be called via:

```
NavigationView 
{
    ...
}.navigationStyleModification()
```

I hope this helps someone who has a similar issue.